# npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/:

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

I am facing a strange problem here with my git-bash and my terminal when I am trying to use `npm install`. I get this error:

[image: my error message]

Someone told me to clear my caches and I did so, but in my case it just changed and now I get no error message. The installing process is never done and I get something like this:

[image: the second error message]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step 1: Delete `package-lock.json` file from your project

Step 2: If your npm version is 5 and above. Then run the following command

```
npm cache verify
```

Step 3: Then run your parcel bunder

```
npm install -g parcel-bundler
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler babel-preset-env
```

Hopefully it should work.

Comment: now I have deleted package-lock.json
and I have done exactly as you said and it didn't solved my problem

Comment: I will till you something I try starting this project from the beginning

Comment: What is ur npm version

Comment: Are you running this in your office environment?

Comment: when I restarted my project it suddenly worked but I need to know what caused this problem so I can avoid it next time ? do you have an idea

Comment: office environment ?

Comment: Because if you are running in offfice, most companies will block npm package. Then you need to set proxy

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I mean to say. Normally compaines have firewall. It will block npm packages. In that case you need to set proxy to bypass it. In your case cache was cleared but it should have been strucked in Windows roaming folder area. After your windows restrart everything was cleared beacuse of the npm cache verify. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17146#issuecomment-310560565) worked for me.

```
rm ./package-lock.json
rm -r ./node_modules
npm cache clear --force
```

You may also want to check that you are not on a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue ("Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.22.35:443")

Solution:

Step 1: Delete package-lock.json file from your project

Step 2: If your npm version is 5 and above. Then run the following command

npm cache verify

Step 3: Then run your parcel bunder

npm install -g parcel-bundler

Then finally, It was showing the "Network Connectivity" issue...!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the answers above didn't help, please try also to run `sudo npm install`.
Sometimes you just don't have permission to write.

Comment: It is not good practice to install npm (or any user similar tools) as super user.

Comment: I agree that this is not good practice but personally I could not fix this through any other means. After hours of browsing I got to the decision to just use sudo for now. I have tried `chown {user} node_modules` `chown {user} package-lock.json` and `chmod u=wrx node_modules` `chmod u=wrx package-lock.json` to give my user ownership and `wrx` permissions to theese files. That didn't help. Any further help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If it happens at work in my case I was open VS Code with elevated permissions. It helps install npm.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I try to install prisma globally, I solved this

1>  `npm cache clear --force`

2>  `npm install npm`

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade npm to v4.6.1.

`npm install npm@4`

Version >= 5 is unstable.

Comment: Nooo it's not the right thing to do

For me I did like my first comment said and it worked for me

Comment: Even if a version had some issues, that doesn't mean all >5 are unstable ...

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: Try to clear the cache first using

```
     npm cache clear --force
```

Step 2: Try to install again

```
    npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as @Chawki's which commented on January. This is a really bad practice and you should consider adding some value to your answer or deleting it.