# Angular Installation on Windows PC failed

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

During my installation of Angular on my PC, It gave me the error below after running this command **ng new my-angular-project**

This is the error message below:

| Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/depd failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/cli/issues

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Idris Samir\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-13T19_49_12_527Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
**The Schematic workflow failed. See above.**

Comment: Firewall problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068565/npm-warn-registry-unexpected-warning-for-https-registry-npmjs-org