# I'm having a problem installing node js and npm packages for tailwind in my terminal

Tags: css, node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I have a big problem and dont know how to solve it. I wanted to start programming with tailwind css for the first time and I have big problems to get the installation process done.

When I follow the installation docs, I have to install tailwind via npm (terminal). I followed 2 YouTube Tutorials as well, but everywhere I get the same result.

Here is the output of the included terminal in VSCode and my Windows Terminal

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNRESET: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tailwindcss failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy,please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\mauri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-06T10_38_54_659Z-debug.log
```

The problem is, I dont use an Proxy for Windows or something?! Does anybody have any solutions?

With best regards Tomiwa

Comment: Hi I recommend you to check the answer posted at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068565/npm-warn-registry-unexpected-warning-for-https-registry-npmjs-org/52068612